# Why I cannot ping 192.168.0.108 (my computer IP?)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ping

Ipconfig says that my IP is 192.168.0.108

```
C:\Users\vbcbu>Reply from 192.168.0.108: Destination host unreachable.ip
'Reply' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\vbcbu>ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 12:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 13:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : www.tendawifi.com
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::3804:2d04:a591:7142%6
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.108
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

C:\Users\vbcbu>
```

I can ping router at 192.168.0.1

I can't ping 192.168.0.108

```
C:\Users\vbcbu>ping 192.168.0.1

Pinging 192.168.0.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.168.0.1:
    Packets: Sent = 2, Received = 2, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 2ms, Maximum = 24ms, Average = 13ms
Control-C
^C
C:\Users\vbcbu>ping 192.168.0.8

Pinging 192.168.0.8 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.0.108: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.0.108: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.0.108: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.0.108: Destination host unreachable.

Ping statistics for 192.168.0.8:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),

C:\Users\vbcbu>ping 192.168.0.8

Pinging 192.168.0.8 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.0.108: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.0.108: Destination host unreachable.
```

Comment: In your ipconfig, your ip address is 192.168.0.108

Comment: ^ what he said. You are pinging `192.168.0.8` and getting a reply from your own machine (`108`) saying `8` is unreachable.

Comment: precisely. that's the issue. Why? Is this normal?

Comment: `8` and `108` are completely different IP addresses. While a machine can potentially have many addresses allocated to it it is typical for them to only be accessible on one address. It's like giving out your address with the house number for someone 50 doors down your street at number 8 and expecting letters to turn up at your door, number 108, instead of theirs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not pinging `192.168.0.108`, you are pinging `192.168.0.8`

As there is apparently no machine on the network at `192.168.0.8`, your own machine `192.168.0.108` is telling you there is nothing there with the response

> Reply from 192.168.0.108: Destination host unreachable.